# Pattern for leftout_state in dynamic programming

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I try to compare two 2D dp solutions.

Particularly the "leftout_state"

```
sum_of_powers: dp[i-1][j - po] (use previous diagonal cell contribute to dp[i][j])

perfect_square: dp[i][j - i*i] (use previous col cell contribute to dp[i][j])
```

My question:

sum_of_powers: why we don't use dp[i][j - po]?

perfect_square: why we don't use dp[i-1][j - i*i]?

in general, is it a pattern?

I put an arrow, pointing to the state

```
https://leetcode.com/problems/ways-to-express-an-integer-as-sum-of-powers/

var numberOfWays = function(n, x) {
    const tar = n;

    const dp = new Array(1+n).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
        return new Array(1+n).fill(0);
    })

    for(let i=0; i<=n; ++i) {
        dp[i][0] = 1;
    }

    const MOD = 10 ** 9 + 7;

    // * b: each item
    for(let i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        const po = i ** x;

        for(let j=1; j<=tar; ++j) {
            if(j >= po) {
                dp[i][j] = (dp[i-1][j] + dp[i-1][j - po]) % MOD; <---------
            } else {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] % MOD;
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[n][tar];
};
```

```
https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/

var numSquares = function(tar) {
    const item_num = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(tar));

    // * b: item_num -> tar
    const dp = new Array(item_num+1).fill(Infinity).map((_, i) => {
        return new Array(tar+1).fill(Infinity);
    });

    for (let i = 0; i <= item_num; i++) {
        dp[i][0] = 0;
    }

    for(let i=1; i<=item_num; ++i) {
        for(j=1; j<=tar; ++j) {
            if(i*i <= j) {
                dp[i][j] = Math.min(1 + dp[i][j - i*i], dp[i-1][j]); <-------------
            } else {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]; // working
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[item_num][tar];
};
```